# Change headline text for post thumbnail meta box

Tags: metabox, post-thumbnails

How can I change the headline text for the post thumbnail meta box in the edit post screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Featured Image box is internally a meta box, added using [`add_meta_box`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) (ref. `edit-form-advanced.php` line no. 128). As far as my research went, there is no filter applied to the meta box title (ref. `template.php` line no. 846). Hence you cant change the metabox title using a filter. Though you can try printing the contents of `global $wp_meta_boxes` (returned blank in my case), or use a jQuery trick to get your job done. But if you ever want to change the inner text, 'Set featured image' (or the html for that matter), you can use the filter `admin_post_thumbnail_html`.

Comment: Great, thanks! I'm satisfied with changing the HTML.